# Facebook graph api friend request sent

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need to use graph API to find out how many people have i sent friend request to and it is pending?
Is it possible to get this information using the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using FQL: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend_request/