# How can I get all the friendship requests sent by me using the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to get all the friendships requests sent by a specific user but found nothing related to this in the Facebook's developer documentation.

Imagine that a user logged in with the Facebook account in my application wants to see all the friendships requests that he has sent and that have not yet been accepted (or declined). Is it possible by using the Graph API to get this list of requests?

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7144021/4056678) but, FQL is discontinued since August 2016.

Comment: FQL isn't deprecated; it's discontinued.  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Comment: @RobertHarvey thank you ,I've edited.  Anyway it is not possible to use the solution given in the question mentioned.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, "is it possible" seldom makes a good question.  Anything is possible given enough time and effort; it's entirely possible to scrape the web pages of Facebook to get the information you want.

Comment: You're right, I've edited it too. I considered using webscrapping for this, but the elements of the Facebook page are created dynamically (with different names) and do not know how complex this can become.

Comment: "Scrapping" is a common misspelling.  :)

Comment: Have you read this?  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/user/friendrequests

Comment: Yes, this brings me the users who sent me requests for friendships, but I would like to get the solicitations that I've sent and that have not yet been accepted or refused. Another thing is that when make a request to this endpoint, a  "`(#12) friend requests is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher`" message is returned. This documentation seems a little outdated.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Why it's duplicated if the solutions of the linked question do not even exist in the documentation? Maybe they worked 2013. Timeline: `sent/pending` -> `FQL` -> `2018?`.

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook, don´t do that. there is no way to do what you want to achieve.